# better way for mapping classes to views using Adapters

Tags: java, android

I have a set of classes in my android application, all of them are deserialized from `JSON` (gson or jackson are not used). All these classes are mapped to some views.

For example I have a list of items and some of fields of class are should be present in this list item.

As soon as I have more than one such list, I do not want to write a `ListAdapter` for each class. So I'm looking for a better way to map fields of class to views in list.

Some time ago I've written simple adapter for mapping `String[]` on number of `views`.

Here it is https://github.com/marwinxxii/ccardstats/blob/master/src/com/github/marwinxxii/ccardstats/gui/TextMappingAdapter.java

Now I have an idea to make all of my classes implement `interface Map`, so I could easily access their fields using methods **get** and **put**. In case of `TextMappingAdapter` I won't need to create `List<String[]>` each time and just pass `List&lt;Map&gt;`, also it would be easier to `deserialize` from `JSON`.

Is it a good solution or there is a better way to do this? I thought about reflection, but it must be slower than implementing a map interface (isn't it?).

Comment: how many fields you need to display...

Comment: number of fields differs from 2 to 5

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add an Interface to your serialized objects and create a general enough adapter that binds to that new Interface

Comment: this is what I am talking about, this interface would be Map. But wouldn't it hurt performance to access fields through Map?

Comment: depends on the complexity of your objects , but in my opinion is more likely to hit performance or sluggishness problems because of a poorly implemented adapter than it is using very complex objects